# Invalid object error when trying to convert from object to integers

Tags: python, pandas, type-conversion, pandas-groupby

I am well aware questions of a similar nature have been asked before, however after trying most conventional methods I am at a complete loss.

I have a dataframe comprising of multiple variables, from which I've selected 5 and grouped those variables to a common attribute: 'City'.

I am trying to derive the unique value from the attribute 'driver_count' based on each City:

```
        city    driver_count    type    date    fare    ride_id
0   Kelseyland  63  Urban   2016-08-19 04:27:52 5.51    6246006544795
1   Kelseyland  63  Urban   2016-04-17 06:59:50 5.54    7466473222333
2   Kelseyland  63  Urban   2016-05-04 15:06:07 30.54   2140501382736
3   Kelseyland  63  Urban   2016-01-25 20:44:56 12.08   1896987891309
4   Kelseyland  63  Urban   2016-08-09 18:19:47 17.91   8784212854829
...
```

Should be simple enough, right? I simply group my dataframe by 'City', then use the pd.unique() function to derive my unique 'driver_count' value.

```
pyber_df_drivers_unique=pyber_df_cities.groupby("city") # Pulls the unique value for the number of drivers in each City
U_pyber_df_drivers = pyber_df_drivers_unique["driver_count"].unique()

>>> city
Alvarezhaven    [21]
Alyssaberg      [67]
Anitamouth      [16]
Antoniomouth    [21]
Aprilchester    [49]
...
    Name: driver_count, dtype: object
```

This is where my trouble begins: I am creating a new dataframe to group all my transformed attributes (means, counts etc. of other variables) so that I can plot my data. The problem is, U_pyber_df_drivers is categorized as an object, not an integer or a numeric type (something probably also indicated by the brackets in the output above).

**pd.to_numeric:**

```
pd.to_numeric(U_pyber_df_drivers)
>>>
ERROR Invalid object type at position 0

#What's at position 0?
U_pyber_df_drivers[0]
>>>
array([21], dtype=int64)
```

I don't understand this error. I have tried other methods such as df.astype(str), df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True), df.infer_objects(), even pd.factorize()... with different types of errors or simply failing to do anything in converting my variable from an object to a numeric type (I was going to list all of those in details, but given that this one error is what started it all, I'd rather understand it to avoid throwing spaghetti at the wall in the future).

Comment: I guess `U_pyber_df_drivers.str[0]` would be enough

Comment: You've got to be kidding me....it worked, thank you....but WHY?

Comment: I can explain, but first, I'd need to know if there is the possibility of more than one value inside your lists? If yes, then this may not be a good solution because `.str[0]` will extract just the first item from each list.

Comment: No, I extracted the 'Drivers Count' variable from my main DataFrame, so there's only one value per 'City' (index) attribute.

Comment: My output is thus: "city
Alvarezhaven    21
Alyssaberg      67
Anitamouth      16
Antoniomouth    21
Aprilchester    49 (....)
Name: driver_count, dtype: int64"

Comment: Well, there you go. Enjoy!

Comment: Was it the brackets in my output that was the problem? Is it something that the pd.unique() function does by automatically assigning an object type to an array (I didn't have the same problem when doing arithmetic arguments like pd.mean or count)?  Thanks again, struggled far too much for something ending up to be so silly.

Comment: Your result was a column of lists, where each list had a single element. So, you just needed to get the first result from them. I showed you how to do that with `.str[0]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated by [@cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4909087/c%E1%B4%8F%CA%9F%E1%B4%85s%E1%B4%98%E1%B4%87%E1%B4%87%E1%B4%85), the `.str[0]` function extracts the first item from a list, and granted my dataframe has only a single element, it worked to convert from object to integer (I am guessing the only reason it assigned integer as a type is because it inferred the type of the array).

Another solution I suppose would have been to pass a dtype argument within the pd.unique() function. If no arguments are passed, I think what happens is that pd.unique() will assign each numeric value as its own list, each defined as object types, and thus we end up with a list embedded in a list ( ex: [ [ 0 ], [ 1 ], [ .. ] ] instead of the intended [ 0, 1, ..] ).